# Mongodb compound index to ensure uniqueness within embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, indexing, unique

I have a document, which looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52ed4a833004dcaf9e224459"),
    "name": "unique name",
    "permission" : [
        {
            "group" : ObjectId("52ed4a973004dcaf9e22445a"),
            "u" : 31
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to ensure that the 'permission' array may only contain one entry with the key 'group' and a specific value. There may be several entries with the same key and different values though.
I tried setting a compound index on a unique field and 'permission.group', but I was still able to insert duplicate documents:

```
db.user.ensureIndex({'name':1, 'permission.group':1}, {unique:1, sparse:1})
```

I also tried setting a compound index on another unique index and permission.group, as recommended in another question on SO.

```
db.user.ensureIndex({name: 1}, {unique: 1, name: 'name_1'})
db.user.ensureIndex({'name_1':1, 'permission.group':1}, {unique:1, sparse:1})
```

but that lead to an error:

```
"err" : "E11000 duplicate key error index:People.user.$name_1_1_permission.group_1  dup key: { : null, : ObjectId('52ed4a973004dcaf9e22445a') }",
```

However, there currently is no user present in the db, that has duplicate permissions set. If I set dropDups to true, this removes all users except one, which contain a permission to the group in question. So, that doesn't work as I would like it to.
Is it possible to set a unique index with mongodb to achieve what I am looking for?

Btw, I am retrieving documents often where specific permissions are set, so I will need an index on the permission array anyway.
As I know this probably be important as well, I will be adding more different value types for the permission array in the future as well. So the 'group' key might not be the only one in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently indexes, unique or not, work upon the entire collection not per subdocument.

If you want some kind of uniqueness on the subdocument you could use query magic:

```
db.c.update({
    name: 'Sammaye',
    'permission.group': {$ne: ObjectId()}
}, {$push:{permission:{group: ObjectId(), u: 31}}});
```

This will of course only update if `sammaye` does not already have that specific `group` entry. Feel free to modify it as you need it.